# Какой способ обмена данными в Си между двумя независимыми процессами Linux самый быстрый по времени?

Tags: linux, c

Как быстрее всего передать 10000 сообщений "Привет" по цепочке из 100 независимых процессов Linux туда и обратно без их потери?

Comment: Общая память на все процессы?

Comment: @andreymal, да, но они не форкнутые.

Comment: Вроде должно быть возможно наладить общую память и без форков (правда, лично я не сишник и не умею)

Comment: @andreymal, см. мой коммент на ответ ниже

Comment: Под "быстрым" можно понимать и "с наименьшей задержкой" и "с наибольшей полосой". Это могут быть разные механизмы.
Я бы посмотрел на очереди сообщений (message queues). Они имеют довольно малую задержку, есть всегда и не требуют сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, это - стандартный механизм ОС?

Comment: Linux не стандартизован, насколько я знаю. То есть в нём вообще нет ничего стандартного. Кое-как стандартизованы отдельные дистрибутивы, заявлено соответствие стандартам отдельных кусков, но вряд ли более того.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1: через файл**

Создайте файл. В каждом процессе открывайте его и записывайте слово. Это хороший вариант, с учетом того, что ввод/вывод так и работает. Функция `puts` помещает массив байтов в `stdout`, файл для вывода.

**Вариант 2: через сокеты(tcp)**

Создайте один процесс сервер по адресу `127.0.0.1`. Другие процессы будут подключатся к нему и пересылать слово.

**Вариант 3: через сокеты(udp)**

На локальном хосте потерь не будет, несмотря на ненадежность протокола. По сравнению с `tcp` не требуется подключение и скорость отправки будет выше.

Comment: рекомендую первый вариант

Comment: Скорее всего все три варианта будут чудовищно медленные даже по сравнению с обычными пайпами

Comment: [shared memory](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) (пример см. в [man shm_open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) (обратите внимание на [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) в нем))

Comment: Unix domain sockets забыли. А это быстро!

Comment: @avp, знаю про mmap, но везде для него примеры только с дочерними процессами.

Comment: @AlexeyLot, в примере из man shm_open mmap должен работать совершенно независимо от родственности процессов.